# directory was detected as file in perl

Tags: linux, perl, file, unix, directory

I tried to use this condition `(-d $var)` in a loop to check how many child directories on the given directory but some folders were detected as a file instead. What happened to the condition that failed to recognized the directory? How can i resolve this problem?

My code is:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if($file =~ m/^\./);
    if (-d $file and -e $file and !$seen{$file}) {
        $seen{$file} = 1;
        push @Dir, "$pwd/$file";
    }
    next if ($file !~ m/\s/i);
    my $new_name = s/\s//g;
    `mv $pwd/$file $pwd/$new_name`;
}
```

Comment: Were those symlinks to directories rather than actual directories?

Comment: nope its an actual directory. :(

Comment: Neat.  What type of filesystem?  Can you show us the code?

Comment: foreach my $file (@files) {
 next if($file =~ m/^\./);   
        if (-d $file and -e $file and !$seen{$file}) {
     $seen{$file} = 1;
            push @Dir, "$pwd/$file";
        }
        next if ($file !~ m/\s/i);
 my $new_name = s/\s//g;
 `mv $pwd/$file $pwd/$new_name`; 
        }

Comment: What are the contents of your `@files` array?  Is it from a `glob` call or a `readdir` call?

Comment: Do you need a `next;` in the code block after `if (-d ...)`?  Otherwise, your directories also get renamed...though the newname code needs some work (`my $newname = $file; $newname =~ s/\s+//g;`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything obvious. However, I did spot a bug.

- You have `my $new_name = s/\s//g;`. You have `=` instead of `=~`.
- You also don'/t say how you get `$new_name` in order to do the substitution.

Neither of these point to your issue itself.

The other possibility is that you use three different tests all anded together. I wonder if you are somehow running into a condition where `-d` passes, but the other conditions aren't true. You might want to separate them out.

I also notice you test whether the file is a directory with `$file`, but when you put the directory name into the `@Dir` array, you prepend it with `$pwd`. What's going on here? Do you need to do `if ( -d "$pwd/$file" )` too?

I recommend that you put in some debug statements to see where you're having an issue.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use File::Copy;

my %seen;
my @dir;
for my $file ( @files ) {
    say qq(DEBUG: Looking at "$file");
    next if $seen{$file};
    say qq(DEBUG: "$file" has not been previously seen);
    $seen{$file} = 1;
    next if $file =~ /^\./;
    say qq(DEBUG: "$file" does not start with a period);
    if ( -d $file ) {
       say qq(DEBUG: "$file" is a directory);
       push @dir, "$pwd/$file;
    }
    else { #DEBUG:
       say qq(DEBUG: "$file" is a file);
   } #DEBUG:
   my $new_name = $file;
   if ( $new_name =~ s/\s+//g ) {
      say qq(DEBUG: Moving file "$file" to "$new_name");
      move $file, $new_name or
        die qq(Couldn't move "$file" to "$new_name");
   }
}
```

- The `use feature qw(say);` allows you to use the `say` command. This is just like `print` except it puts a new line on the end for you.
- The `use File::Copy` module allows you to use the `move` statement. No more shelling out and being OS dependent. Perl comes with a whole flock of modules that make your life easier. For example, the `File::Find` allows you to find files and directories.
- I include all files and directories in `%seen` (why not?) and check for that first before checking if it's a directory.
- I use the `move $file, $new_name or die qq(...)` to see if that move statement worked. You should always test the output of your functions -- especially fail prone functions like moving a file name or copying it, etc.
- Notice I do `if ( $new_name =~ s/\s+//g )`. This allows me to test whether `$new_name` has a space and remove those spaces all at the same time.
- The `qq(...)` is like a double quote, but you can use quotation marks in the string without having to back quote them. This way, I can see if my file name has a space or a NL on the end of the name.

Once you have your code working, you can easily search for the string `DEBUG:` and remove the noise.

I haven't tested my code (It's hard when the program isn't really complete and I don't know what your data looks like), but I hope you get the idea. The `DEBUG:` statements will allow you to see more what is going on in your code and help you find your logic issue. About 1/2 the time the problem isn't in the program, but in the data.

Comment: There is no point in using `File::Copy` when all that is needed is the Perl built-in `rename` function.

Comment: Dang. I forgot about `rename`. I saw the system call to `mv`, and said, _Hey, you should use `File::Copy`!_. Yes, in this case (especially since this is Unix), the `rename` command will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me a while back writing a script similar to this.  Try using the entire path with the [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) method `catfile`.  I am assuming you are running this in a separate directory from the actual files and directories.

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

my $dir = getcwd; # Or whatever directory name you want
my $full_name = File::Spec->catfile($dir, $file);
if (-d $full_name) {
  # Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of problems with your code. Why do you think the `-d` test is failing? The same rename is applied to both directories and files; the only difference is that directories are additionally pushed onto the `@dir` array the first time they are seen.

I'm not clear exactly what you want to do, but this version renames only files that contain whitespace characters in their name.

```
foreach my $file (@files) {

    next if $file =~ m/^\./;

    if (-d $file ) {
        push @dir, "$pwd/$file" unless $seen{$file}++;
        next;
    }

    my $new_name = $file;
    if ($new_name =~ s/\s//g) {
        rename "$pwd/$file", "$pwd/$new_name" or warn $!;
    }
}
```